# ZF2 doesn't load vendor's plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've got a problem with my vendor/MyVendor/Mvc/Plugin/Url.php - it just doesn't load. I'm sure that vendor is loaded. I have moved MyVendor from another application, but i'm sure that i configured it's loading well. I tried make php-super-error (asdasda witout ;) and i'm sure that file is not loaded.

**Is that possible that there are differences between 2.0 and current version in plugins loading?** (that's my question)

The only difference in my app is version of ZF2 engine, so configuration should be ok.

I didn't forget about register namespaces etc

Comment: What type of error do you have?

Comment: Hello, i have no error, my plugin is just not loaded. It should override default mvc/controller/plugin/url.

Comment: Is your application or the one you're copying this file from use Composer? Normally it creates and manages the 'vendor' folder.

Comment: Aww, the problem was that another module got url factor... i'm not sure why programmers put it there... So topic is cloesed, but thanks for try!

Answer (score 0):

if you use composer to load add you module or plugin to autoload_classmap.php, autoload_namespaces.php

see example below

vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php

```
    return array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools\\Module'    => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/Module.php');
```

vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php

```
return array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/src');
```